# Linear Independence easy question

Tags: linear-algebra

I have these vectors $B = \{u, v, w\}$ with

$$u = (-1, 1, -1),\, v = (19, 10, -9),\, w = (-1, x, y)$$

And i want to prove that these vectors are linearly independent.

I have no problem to proove that three vectors without unknown variables are linearly indepedent but i have difficulties in this that i have two unknown variables $(x, y)$.

I find that $\det(B)$ is $-28x - 29y -1$ but i do not know how this helps.

The actual question is to prove that B forms a basis in R3

PS. New to Linear Algebra, dont shoot !

Comment: It's worth noting that if $x=1$, $y=-1$, then $u=w$, and linear independence is out of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question. In fact, the vectors are linearly independent whenever the determinant $-28x -29y -1$ is not equal to zero. So, the answer depends on $x$ and $y$.

**How I know this**: The determinant can be thought of as a function of $m$ vectors in $m$-dim'l space, in which case one of the properties that characterizes it is that if one of its inputs is a linear combination of some or all of the others, then the function will evaluate to zero. Also, the function will evaluate to zero only in this case. Hence, a set of $m$ vectors in an $m$-dim'l space will be linearly independent if and only if their determinant is nonzero. See [this section of wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant) for more details, specifically where it says that properties 1, 7, and 8 completely characterize the determinant.

**Back to your specific question**. Set $$-28x - 29y - 1 = 0$$ and rewrite it as $$y = - \frac{28}{29}x  -\frac{1}{29}.$$ Your three vectors are linearly independent when $x,y$ lie away from this line, which you can easily plot now that it's written in slope-intercept form. And since you want to know when these vectors form a basis for $V := \mathbb{R}^3$, and since you know that any linearly independent set of 3 vectors in $V$ forms a basis, you know that these vectors form a basis when $x,y$ lie away from the line given above.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So B is a basis of R3 for x,yE R - {1, -1} right?

Comment: No, $B$ is a basis for $R^3$ for all $(x,y)$ such that $y \neq -\frac{28}{29}x - \frac{1}{29}$.

Comment: Wait, sorry, laughing_man is correct here. The point $(x,y) = (1,-1)$ is only one of many points for which $B$ fails to be a basis.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. The assignment also defines that x, y >= 0 (i missed it) so it does makes sense